# how can i filter store with two fields in extjs?

Tags: php, extjs, filter, store

i have created 3 store named chapter, subject and standard in extjs. 
In Chapter store i have field subjectid and stanrdid now i want to filter my chapter store according to value selected in subject and standard.

I am able to filter chapters from any one filter but not able to filter record from both ids.

Comment: There is no question...

Comment: @MatthewBaker Read the question title. There is a questionmark ;).

Comment: my problem is how to filter by 2 columns in store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic filter example is shown below.  See the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-filters).  You could also try the [Store.filterBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) method in a similar fashion.

```
filters: [
    function(item) {
        if (item.subject == selectedSubject && item.standard == selectedStandard){
          return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
]
```